# Is Backward chaining supported? Are there any examples?

Tags: rule-engine, durable-rules

I am evaluating durable-rules against Drools and I see mention of "Backward chaining" in Drools documentation - but not in durable-rules.

Is this feature supported by durable-rules? Is there an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks for asking the question. durable-rules doesn't support backward chaining. It is in the plans for future support.

Comment: hope implement the feature